# ¿Cómo concatenar dos String en Android?

Tags: java, android, string

Quiero realizar la concatenación de dos `String`:

```
String nombre = adornoF.getNombre();
String prefijo = ga.getsid();
String all = nombre + prefijo;
```

Tanto `getNombre()` como `getsid()` devuelven un `String`.

¿Está bien planteado o hay una manera mejor?

Comment: Como un ejemplo puedes realizarlo así, pero como buena práctica, por ejemplo si es un proyecto en el cual deseas escalabilidad, es mejor optimizar desde un inicio.

Comment: De acuerdo con lo planteado en Meta en [¿Alteración del significado de la pregunta: Concatenar 2 String?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1879/83) (aceptado y con varios votos a favor), procedo a revertir las dos últimas ediciones.

Comment: Borch: como ves, tu pregunta está recibiendo [múltiples revisiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/65327/revisions). ¿Cuál era tu objetivo final a la hora de plantearla? ¿Preguntar por dos o múltiples strings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Las formas de concatenar dos `String` son:

---

Usando el operador `+` :

```
String a = "hola !";
String b = "\nStackoverflow !";    
String resultado = a + b;
```

---

mediante el método [concat()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) :

```
String a = "hola !";
String b = "\nStackoverflow !";
String resultado = a.concat(b);
```

---

Usando la clase [StringBuffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) y el método append() :

```
String a = "hola !";
String b = "\nStackoverflow !";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append(a);
sb.append(b);
String resultado = sb.toString();
```

---

Usando la clase [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), y el método [append()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.String)) :

```
String a = "hola !";
String b = "\nStackoverflow !";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(a);
sb.append(b);
String resultado = sb.toString();
```

En los 3 casos obtendrías el mismo resultado, sin embargo como buena practica lo mejor es usar [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) para concatenar el text en el buffer y obtener un solo objeto `String` mediante `toString()`.

---

Documentación Android:

- Clase **[StringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)**
- Clase **[StringBuffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)**
- Método **[concat()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String))**

Comment: Puesto que esto está etiquetado como [tag:android], entonces sería mejor poner enlaces a [`https://developer.android.com/reference`](https://developer.android.com/reference).

Comment: A mi me gusta más apostar por la optimización y consistencia del código, a la larga gratifica más la experiencia de usuario @Jorseys  +1

Comment: Dejando aparte un momento la cuestión de la mantenibilidad del código. Despues de analizar en profundidad esta cuestión he llegado a conclusión de que usar el operador +, en este caso en particular, es más eficiente que usar StringBuilder. Al final de [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/65400/301) tienen la demostración. @Webserveis

Answer (score 7):

Así está bien, también puedes gastar la función `concat()` de java de la siguiente forma:

```
String all = prefijo.concat(nombre);
```

Answer (score 7):

Hay otra manera es usar `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(nombre);
sb.append(prefijo);
String cadena_final = sb.toString();
```

En bucles es más óptimo usar `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder() ;
for(int i= 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++ )
    sb.append( "a" );
String s= sb.toString() ;
```

Extraído en [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453485/3464919)

Aquí hay la [discusión cual es mejor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java) evidentemente depende de su uso, si es solo una vez pues mejor usar `+` pero si es para ir construyendo una cadena a partir de un bucle, pues mejor `StringBuilder`

Comment: has sido *ninja'deado* ;) xDD

Comment: La discusión no es del todo exacta. Hay que tomar en cuenta que Android Runtime ≠ Java Runtime Environment.

Comment: @PaulVargas el Android Studio cuando detecta que usas string + string, te sale un warning que te recomiendo usar StringBuilder, hasta tiene un conversor automatico alt+intro. Supongo que es solo si usas muchos concats donde realmente le sacas el jugo.

Comment: Android Studio puede recomendar lo que quiera... También eclipse, NetBeans, etc., Pero... ¿qué hace el compilador de Android? ¿Utiliza internamente una instancia (o varias) de `StringBuilder` para reemplazar el operador **`+`**? ¿Qué tipo de optimización hace (como la JVM de IBM)?

Comment: Esto es lo mejor, usar StringBuilder. como buena práctica, donde podemos observar beneficios cuando nuestros sistemas tienden a ser robustos!.

Comment: En el link que pones la respuesta aceptada y más votada dice que lo mejor es utilizar el operador +. Que es lo contrario de lo que pones en tu respuesta. Mi análisis del bytecode coindice con la respuesta en inglés.

Answer (score 7):

## Está muy bien, no lo cambies [prematuramente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizaci%C3%B3n_prematura).

A la hora de hacer un programa hay varias cosas que son importantes, entre otras:

- El consumo de CPU
- El consumo de memoria, disco y otros recursos.
- **La corrección**. Que el programa haga lo que de el se espera.

El tercer punto siempre es importante. En todas las línes de código es importante que hagan lo que de ellas se espera.
Los otros dos puntos no siempre son igual de importantes. Si tu concatenación de cadenas consume el 0.01% del tiempo de tu programa poco vas a ganar optimizándola. Si consume el 20% entonces sí vale la pena.

Para hacer que un programa sea **correcto** es importante utilizar código que sea **sencillo** y **facil de entender** y **mantener**.

El código que has escrito :

```
String all = nombre + prefijo;
```

cumple esos requisitos.

Un código potencialmente más eficiente como :

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder( nombre.length() + prefijo.length() );
b.append(nombre);
b.append(prefijo);
String all = b.toString();
```

no es mucho más difícil de entender. Pero si siempre programas así un programa de 10,000 líneas tendrá 40,000 y ahí sí vas a notar la diferencia.
¿Por qué perjudicar la legibilidad de tu programa para obtener una mejora de eficiencia que podría ser insignificante?

### Conclusión : esfuérzate en que tu código sea sencillo, mantenible y correcto.

Y cuando funcione bien pásale un profiler y optimiza los cuellos de botella.

## ¿Es StringBuilder más rápido en este caso?

Supongamos que, por el motivo que sea, hemos llegado a la conclusión de que su rendimiento es crítico. ¿Usar StrinBuilder es más rápido?

Consideremos el código con el operador +:

```
class A {
  static void test() {
    String a = "hola !";
    String b = "\nStackoverflow !";    
    String resultado = a + b;
  }
}
```

Y el código con StringBuilder:

```
class A {
  static void test() {
    String a = "hola !";
    String b = "\nStackoverflow !";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(a);
    sb.append(b);
    String resultado = sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Este es el código en bytecodes para el caso del operador + :

```
C:\test>"C:\dev\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\javac" A.java
C:\test>"C:\dev\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\javap" -c A
Compiled from "A.java"
class A {
  A();
    Code:
     100: aload_0
     101: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":
()V
     102: return

  static void test();
    Code:
       1: ldc           #2                  // String hola !
       2: astore_0
       3: ldc           #3                  // String \nStackoverflow !
       4: astore_1
       5: new           #4                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       6: dup
       7: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
       8: aload_0
       9: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      10: aload_1
      11: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      12: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      13: astore_2
      14: return
}
```

Y este es el código en bytecodes para el caso del StringBuilder :

```
C:\test>"C:\dev\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\javac" A.java
C:\test>"C:\dev\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\javap" -c A
Compiled from "A.java"
class A {
  A();
    Code:
     100: aload_0
     101: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":
()V
     102: return

  static void test();
    Code:
       1: ldc           #2                  // String hola !
       2: astore_0
       3: ldc           #3                  // String \nStackoverflow !
       4: astore_1
       5: new           #4                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       6: dup
       7: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      7b: astore_2
       8: aload_2
      8b: aload_0
       9: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      9b: pop
      9c: aload_2
      10: aload_1
      11: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     11b: pop
     11c: aload_2
      12: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      13: astore_3
      14: return
}
```

Los números que salen (del 1 al 14, y los de las letras) no son reales, los he modificado yo para que resulte más fácil de entender la explicación.

Lo primero que llama la atención es que el código del operador + se compila a StringBuilder.
Lo segundo es que el código del StringBuilder tiene las mismas 14 instruciones de bytcode que el del operador + (las líneas sin letra b o c). Excepto por diferencias en el parámetro, como en la línea 8 (astore_0 o astore_2), pero esta diferencia no afecta al rendimiento.
Lo que sí afecta son las 6 instrucciones extra de bytecode (7b, 8b, 9b, 9c, 11b y 11c) que tiene el código de StringBuilder.

No es código bytecode de JVM lo que le llega al dispositivo Android. Este se convierte a DEX. Y luego a código nativo. Pero con lo visto ya está claro. Si uno de esos pasos intermedios optimizase el código del StringBuilder como mucho alcanzaría al del operador + optimizado, en ningún caso lo mejoraría.

### Conclusión: StringBuilder es más lento en este caso en particular.

¿Debemos renegar pues de Stringbuilder y usar siempre el operador +?
Por supuesto que no. Para concatenar dos cadenas es mejor el operador +, pero considera el caso de un array de 1000 cadenas en que quieres concatenarlas todas para hacer una sola cadena.
Me atrevería a decir que con StringBuilder será más rápido:

```
String[] cadenas = new String[1000];
// ... Código que pone 1000 cadenas en el array ...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for ( String cad : cadenas )
  sb.append(cad);
String resultado = sb.toString();
```

Y no solo será más rápido(1) sino que ese código también es igual de fácil de entender y mantenible que la alternativa con el operador +:

```
String[] cadenas = new String[1000];
// ... Código que pone 1000 cadenas en el array ...
String resultado = "";
for ( String cad : cadenas )
  resultado += cad;
```

(1) Salvo que el compilador también sea capaz de optimizar el código del operador +.

Comment: ¿según tu, no optimizar al inicio es correcto?, tal vez piensas que el OP esta realizando un "hello world" ⤜(ʘ_ʘ)⤏ , lee el articulo que tu mismo comentas, "diseñar primero, luego codificar el diseño", se puede perder tiempo realizando código "sencillo" como concatenar con + que al final posiblemente terminarás cambiando!

Comment: Comentas que "Hay varias cosas importantes como : El consumo de CPU, El consumo de memoria, disco y otros recursos.La corrección. Que el programa haga lo que de el se espera".... pero esta bien concatenar Strings con +  ?????? ᕦ ´• ᴥ •` ᕥ

Comment: Lo dice [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth), [The Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) Pág671:Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%

Comment: He leído lo que comenta el DonaldK Knuth, Como ejemplo puedes realizar una aplicación desktop sin preocuparte en varios casos de "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs" ...Pero en el caso de dispositivos con recursos limitados, créeme que es muy diferente.

Comment: También una cosa mucho más importante es la consistencia del código, muchos problemas de los programas deriva de eso, usar conectores primarios porque son más legibles el programador, pero a la larga puede ser un coladero, mejor usar métodos y si son más eficientes a la segunda pasada pues mejor que mejor.

Comment: -1 me parece **increíble tanto análisis para determinar que es más rápido concatenando 2 strings**, si mediante el operador + o mediante el uso de la clase StringBuilder , bueno *entonces que use + cuando concatene dos Strings, esa es la conclusión?*  ಠ_ಠ . Véase, por ejemplo, (How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java]

Comment: Resulta difícil entender lo que escribes @Jorgesys . ¿Te parece que hay algo mal en el análisis? ¿Qué? ¿O lo que te parece mal es que analice la cuestión? La conclusión está en la respuesta : "StringBuilder es más lento en este caso en particular." Los microbenchmark no los he tratado en mi respuesta por lo que tu enlace no me ayuda a mejorar mi respuesta.

Comment: Bueno primeramente estaban mofandose con ["No vas a necesitarlo "](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI) y ahora realizas este análisis, para que un análisis si no es necesario?  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36947864#36947864  Bueno entonces la recomendación es usar + ?

Comment: Yo pensaba que cambiar a StringBuilder no era una mejora. Despues de analizarlo he descubierto que incluso puede ser un empeoramiento. Claro que es necesario, he aprendido algo nuevo. Nadie se ha mofado de ti, solo te hacemos ver tu error, lo cual te ayuda a mejorar, si quieres.

Comment: ¿Pero es prueba no seria mejor hacerla correr en runtime en Android con un dispositivo y ver si da lo mismo?

Comment: En realidad, cuando concatenas dos `String` en Java, el bytecode generado usa un `StringBuilder` para juntar los contenidos de ambas cadenas y se llama al método `toString`. No sé si esto sea "más lento". Por experiencia, creo que lo mejor sería usar el operador `+` porque son solo dos cadenas. Si hablamos de múltiples cadenas, depende mucho de cómo se deban concatenar para que se aplique el resultado final.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción que nadie ha mencionado es usar [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

```
String s1 = "hola ";
String s2 = "mundo!";
String concatenado = String.format("%s%s", s1, s2);
System.out.println(concatenado);
```

Resultado:

```
hola mundo!
```

Comment: ¿Qué ventajas aporta esa forma de hacerlo con respecto a la que usa el autor de la pregunta?

Comment: Que puedes aplicar algún formato extra sin concatenar más cadenas y es más sencillo de mantener que la concatenación por +. En términos de performance, 0.0001 y 0.001 no hacen daño respecto al performance general de la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, vamos a hacer un reto a los cuatro. Digamos a:

- **operador +**
- **concat**
- **StringBuffer**
- **StringBuilder**

que nos concatenen una cadena:

- a. 100,000 veces
- b. 10,000 veces
- c. 1,000 veces
- d. 100 veces
- e. 2 veces

y veamos cuál es más eficiente de los 4.

En cada prueba se usa el código tal y como funciona internamente.

**Nota**:

La prueba ha sido hecha en Java, en una PC. Sería interesante correrla en Android (quizá con menos valores, por ejemplo 10,000 cadenas)... sería interesante ver el resultado.

El código original es de las 100,000 veces. Para otros valores cambiar la variable `ITERATION`:

**Código:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Pruebas{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        final int ITERATION = 100_000;
        String s = "";

        // String Concatenation using + operator
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATION; i++) {
            s = s + Integer.toString(i);
        }
        long duration = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000;
        System.out.println("operador +  \t Tiempo (en micro) para " + ITERATION + " cadenas " + duration);

        // Using String concat() method
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATION; i++) {
            s.concat(Integer.toString(i));

        }
        duration = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000;
        System.out.println("concat () \t Tiempo (en micro) para " + ITERATION + " cadenas " + duration);

    // StringBuffer example to concate String in Java
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(); // default size 16
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATION; i++) {
            buffer.append(i);
        }

        duration = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000;
        System.out.println("StringBuffer \t Tiempo (en micro) para " + ITERATION + " cadenas "  + duration);

        // StringBuilder example to concate two String in Java
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATION; i++) {
            builder.append(i);
        }
        duration = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000;
        System.out.println("StringBuilder \t Tiempo (en micro) para " + ITERATION + " cadenas "  + duration);
    }
}
```

---

**Resultado (a)**

```
operador +       Tiempo (en micro) para 100000 cadenas 123968461
concat ()        Tiempo (en micro) para 100000 cadenas 76363967
StringBuffer     Tiempo (en micro) para 100000 cadenas 25808
StringBuilder    Tiempo (en micro) para 100000 cadenas 1131
```

**Resultado (b)**

```
operador +       Tiempo (en micro) para 10000 cadenas 3631316
concat ()        Tiempo (en micro) para 10000 cadenas 1058666
StringBuffer     Tiempo (en micro) para 10000 cadenas 5719
StringBuilder    Tiempo (en micro) para 10000 cadenas 1851
```

**Resultado (c)**

```
operador +       Tiempo (en micro) para 1000 cadenas 41713
concat ()        Tiempo (en micro) para 1000 cadenas 33116
StringBuffer     Tiempo (en micro) para 1000 cadenas 1885
StringBuilder    Tiempo (en micro) para 1000 cadenas 1585
```

**Resultado (d)**

```
operador +       Tiempo (en micro) para 100 cadenas 20303
concat ()        Tiempo (en micro) para 100 cadenas 1417
StringBuffer     Tiempo (en micro) para 100 cadenas 2183
StringBuilder    Tiempo (en micro) para 100 cadenas 122
```

**Resultado (e)**

```
operador +       Tiempo (en micro) para 2 cadenas 448
concat ()        Tiempo (en micro) para 2 cadenas 35
StringBuffer     Tiempo (en micro) para 2 cadenas 29
StringBuilder    Tiempo (en micro) para 2 cadenas 18
```

Comment: ¿Y el tiempo de calentamiento para la JVM? Deberías obtener menos de 1 μs para 2 cadenas, sea el método que sea. Es una muy buena idea, pero sin ese tiempo de calentamiento, esto debería merecer -1.

Comment: Mucha razón tiene Paul Vargas. No considerarlo quita toda la validez a los benchmark.

Comment: El OP preguntaba esto _¿Esta bien planteado o hay una manera mejor?_ y yo soy como Tomás : ver para creer. Y he aquí que surgen los apologistas de la JVM. La idea era mostrar la eficacia de cada uno.

Comment: Cedano, tu respuesta puede acabar siendo magnífica. La optimización temprana es la raiz de todos los males. Pero para cuando haya que optimizar tu respuesta sería super útil. Si tiene los benchmarks bien hechos. ¡Animo hombre, tu eres capaz! Seguro que cuando la revise mañana (o cuando puedas corregirla), te podré dar un +2.

Comment: Esta respuesta podría considerarse también como correcta, aporta más información e incluso demostración por medio de benchmarking sobre lo que pregunta el OP, los argumentos para calificarla me parecen algo estrictos, incluso las votaciones, en algunos caso veo que responder poco es mejor que esforzarse en una mejor respuesta! ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Jorgesys Tal como está, es un *benchmarking* **incorrecto**. Véase, por ejemplo, [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) También [Why many Java performance tests are wrong](http://stuq.nl/weblog/2009-01-28/why-many-java-performance-tests-are-wrong).

Comment: Sabes @PaulVargas quería agregar a mi comentario "no hablo de micro-benchmark porque luego me atacan" hahaha!, pero al final salio el tema, se de la importancia de micro-benchmarking pero te puedo comentar que actualmente realizando apps android o .NET con C# no he visto la necesidad de micro benchmark, la razón es que la diferencia es notable en cuanto a performance, por ejemplo cuando realizas varias concatenaciones con + o concat() que usando StringBuilder!. Las  pruebas que realiza A. Cedano pueden mostrar las mismas conclusiones que se tendrían si se realizara micro-benchmarking.

Comment: @Jorgesys Qué `StringBuilder` es superior al operador `+` en múltiples concatenaciones no está a discusión. Lo que está a discusión es que ésta "medición" no está considerando el comportamiento de la JVM (o más precisamente, del ART). Adicionalmente, cuando se trata, como en este caso, de concatenar dos cadenas, el compilador internamente optimiza la instrucción para tener el mismo rendimiento de un `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Perdonen ustedes pero la pregunta no era sobre los benchmark. La intención era reforzar con un ejemplo lo afirmado en la mayoría de las respuestas indicando al mismo tiempo , con código, como funciona **internamente** cada método. Es curioso que los esfuerzos que se hacen por ayudar o aportar mejores soluciones son en cierto sentido descalificados por gente que no lo piensa dos veces antes de apretar el botoncito. Formular está respuesta toma su tiempo y apretar el botón menos de un segundo. Hay ahí una gran diferencia.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos te recuerdo que el OP no preguntaba sobre cómo se hace un benchmark optimizado , sino sobre cuál es la forma más óptima de concatenar cadenas. Si consideras que eso es lo importante podrías tomarte el tiempo de hacer un ejemplo con un benchmark optimizado y publicarlo, entonces te cedería el paso borrando mi respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano En mi respuesta he añadido un análisis del bytecode que genera el operador + y el StringBuilder. En efecto, la pregunta no era sobre los benchmark, pero un benchmark incorrecto no responde la pregunta. Si lees mi respuesta verás que, tanto antes como después de editarla, sí que me pensé bastante la cuestión. No votamos negativo a la ligera. ¿Cual es la alternativa? ¿Dejar una respuesta incorrecta como si fuese buena? Eso perjudica a quien la lea y sobretodo te perjudica a ti, A. Cedano, pues te priva de la oportunidad de mejorar.

Comment: O, en el caso de que yo este equivocado, me priva a mi de la oportunidad de mejorar. Colaboremos juntos en descubrir cual es la mejor forma de responder la pregunta y saldremos todos ganando.

Comment: Bueno primeramente descalifican esta respuesta, se mofan con ["No vas a necesitarlo "](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI) y ahora modificas tu respuesta agregando un análisis, ¿no es necesario o sí lo es?  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36947864#36947864

Comment: Mal micro benchmark, malos resultados... Si vas a hacer un micro benchmark, por lo menos usar un framework como JMH o seguir [estas recomendaciones](http://stackoverflow.com/a/513259/1065197).

Answer (score -2):

Lo que te sugiero es que uses `StringBuilder`.

El problema con los `Strings` en java es que son *inmutables* y cada vez que trabajas con ellas crea un objeto. Con pocos procesos, el coste es irrelevante pero ante un gran proyecto, `StringBuilder` da mejor rendimiento y a su vez menor gasto de memoria.

<sub>(aunque el GarbajeCollector ya se ocupará de esto ultimo)</sub>

Ej:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append(nombre);
stringBuilder.append(prefijo);

String all = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: StringBuilder no da un mejor rendimiento en este caso particular.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos *" Con pocos procesos, el coste es irrelevante pero ante un gran proyecto, StringBuilder da mejor rendimiento"*. No digo que en este caso de mejor rendimiento. Y no entiendo por que la respuesta de WebServeis tiene menos votos negativos (antes de la edicion era igual que la mia y tenia los mismos votos que tiene ahora)

Comment: StringBuilder da mejor rendimiento en bucles y peor en concatenación directa de dos cadenas (y probablemente tam bién de un número constante de cadenas concatenadas diréctamente). Lo cual no tiene nada que ver con tener muchos o pocos procesos o con el tamaño del proyecto. Lo de los votos da para un estudio sociológico :) Yo os he votado igual a ambos.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos con *procesos* me refiero al que se está tratando, la concatenacion de cadenas. gracias por la aclaracion y tu voto (sea cual sea xD)